# Output to system.log stops at 12:00 a.m. each day

Tags: cassandra

Running: Cassandra 2.1.8.689 | DSE 4.7.3 on Linux 2.6

Configured logback.xml.  Cassandra stops writing to log file at midnight each day.  Last entry in log file:

INFO  [CompactionExecutor:6550] 2017-01-05 23:59:58,928INFO ...

After changing filename in logback.xml (ie. system1.log to system2.log), writing resumes.  The same behavior is consistent across 6 nodes.

Thank you Aaron.  Logback details below.

```
<configuration scan="true">
  <appender name="FIX_WINDOW_BASED_FILE" 

class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${cassandra.logdir}/system.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
  <fileNamePattern>${cassandra.logdir}/system%i.log</fileNamePattern>
  <minIndex>1</minIndex>
  <maxIndex>31</maxIndex>
</rollingPolicy>

<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
  <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>

<encoder>
  <pattern>%-5level [%thread] %date{ISO8601} %marker %F:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
  <!-- old-style log format
  <pattern>%5level [%thread] %date{ISO8601} %F (line %L) %msg%n</pattern>
  -->
</encoder>
```

Problem resolved.  After upgrading DSE from 4.7.3 to 4.8.11, output to the system.log is working fine.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the contents of your logbook.xml file here?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to control this behavior in your logback.xml file.  In that file should be an `<appender>` section, which should look something like this:

```
  <appender name="stash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <file>/var/log/cassandra/system.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/var/log/cassandra/system.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 5 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
   </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>
```

My guess is that the file rollover is triggered at midnight, but there must be something in your `<fileNamePattern>` preventing it from creating a new file.